# Eigenvalues of large symmetric matrices

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

When I try to compute the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of [a very large graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3ytliwfcgsdgul/c500.m?dl=0) I get, what can be charitably described as, garbage. In particular, since the graph is four-regular, the eigenvalues should be in $[-4, 4]$ but they are visibly not. I used Matlab (via MATLink), and got the same problems, so this is clearly an issue that transcends mathematica. The question is: what is the best way to deal with it. (the obvious solution -setting precision to 100 - makes Mathematica run out of memory, and would probably take forever if it did not).

Comment: Do you need all the eigenvalues, or just the first (or last) few?

Comment: @J.M. I need all of them, alas...

Comment: I'm kind of wondering what sort of computer would it take to get an accurate eigensystem of a $27450\times27450$ matrix, if so... in any event, did you at least try to compare the results of taking the first few and last few eigenvalues with increasing precision?

Comment: Did you get the same results in MATLAB and Mathematica?  Are sure that your graph is correctly specified?

Comment: Have you tried doing `Eigenvalues@N@matrix` ?

Comment: Well, the eigenvalues of  a $3000\times3000$ matrix (also coming from a graph) are quite accurate (I have sophisticated ways to tell), and take a few seconds on my MacBook Pro). I am happy to wait a few minutes (or an hour) for the results.

Comment: @george2079 I am not sure I understand the question. If you don't N[] the matrix, the computation takes (literally) forever.

Comment: @mikado I did not compare them one by one, but they are both garbage. And yes, the graph is correctly specified (you can run VertexDegree[] on it with expected results, and ConnectedComponents[] (ditto)).

Comment: I didn't realize how big it was !

Comment: @J.M. Maybe it needs supercomputer [Tianhe-2](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=rA9WU-iZFAdvyebvr0o4gT_Fbui8WE2D6UuVQ2mOKMYleZkL4UOUXqFa4R2Jumm_6GQ3zxYJg4rxjezPv9uUGIgEX5ob7QgOJanTCXrPpcOduplEOReXvd7Td8BypS9K6Wu-BgjkDchekJvrA-T2WxniafKhkW66AmQOpXBI5h77McuH0JU8sUsxJyWwksTI) :)

Answer (score 5):

Igor,

I tried this and got a result with all eigenvalues in the range `[-4,4]`:

```
graph = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3ytliwfcgsdgul/c500.m?dl=1"];
adjacency = AdjacencyMatrix[graph];
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[N[adjacency]];
```

Check the length:

```
Length[eigenvalues] (* gives: 27,450 *)
```

Check the minimum and maximum values:

```
MinMax[eigenvalues] (* gives: {-3.46169, 3.99988} *)
```

Plot the eigenvalues:

```
ListPlot[eigenvalues]
```

[image]

I placed the computed eigenvalues in this cloud object:

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-7053ce31-817f-4643-aec1-eda27051bba6/for-igor-rivin

Is this what you're after? If not, can you clarify your question perhaps (with code)?

Comment: What sort of computer did you use? My original bug was manifested on an OS X mathematica, but on Windows things seem to work fine - which seems to mean it is a virtual memory problem of some sort.

Comment: (Commenting from memory, I may have to correct details later) I used my Windows 10 desktop machine, with an i7 processor and 32GB of memory. During the computation the task manager was showing about 16GB of memory use (for all processes). I can check into Mac, it is possible that the numerics library performs differently on the platform in this case.